# How do I print out a response from an API call Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, response

I'm looking to print out the response from an API call with Kickbox's api.

This is what I have

```
require "kickbox"

client   = Kickbox::Client.new('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
kickbox  = client.kickbox()
response = kickbox.verify("test@example.com")

puts response
```

I'm not getting any response when trying to run the file in my terminal.

Comment: try `puts response.inspect` to see what response returns

Comment: Or just p response should work

Comment: @LucaBruzzone that fixed it! How come P works but not puts?

Comment: `p` in ruby equals `puts object.inspect`, while  `puts` equals  `object.to_s` . There's also `pp` which stands for *pretty print*, you need to require the library though.

Comment: yeah but we are devs so we are kinda lazy so p is better than puts object.inspect just because is shorter

Answer (score 1):

try `response.body`

```
{
  "result"  =>"unknown",
  "reason"  =>"no_connect",
  "role"  =>true,
  "free"  =>false,
  "disposable"  =>false,
  "accept_all"  =>false,
  "did_you_mean"  =>nil,
  "sendex"  =>0.35,
  "email"  =>"test@example.com",
  "user"  =>"test",
  "domain"  =>"example.com",
  "success"  =>true,
  "message"  =>nil
}
```

You can also get the response time and balance from headers from `response.headers`

```
{
  "content-type"  =>"application/json",
  "x-kickbox-balance"  =>"99",
  "x-kickbox-response-time"=>"17"
}
```